# Set up Scheuled Task to create Excel File and send email with attachment in C# Console application

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I had a problem where a scheduled task would not send out an email with an attachment in a C# console application.  It took me a long time to figure out the solution (it is working now), so I wanted to share what the two issues were so others can find the solution easily.

There were two problems:

1) When saving the file to the directory I could not use a relative directory like:

```
DirectoryInfo currentDir = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
attachmentPath = currentDir.Parent.Parent.FullName + @"\Reports\" + startDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") + " - " + endDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") + ".xlsx";
```

I had to explicitly set the directory like:

```
attachmentPath = @"E:\reports\Excel Automated Reports\WebEx Daily Report\ExcelReportAutomation\Reports\" + startDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") + " - " + endDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") + ".xlsx";
```

After, I did that the file was being created and saved but still was not emailing it out.  If I sent out an email without an attachment then the email would go out.  The way to fix this issue is by setting the **Start in (optional)** option in the edit action for the scheduled task.

[image]

I repeat this is not a question but I am trying to lay out a solution for people who come across the same issue.

Comment: I don't think your first attempt looks like a relative path.  I'd suggest using Path.Combine instead of concatenating the path strings where possible.

Comment: This is exactly the behavior I would have expected - if you dont specify where to run the app from the app will run from probably windows, or windows system32.. so you should always be specific.

Comment: @BugFinder I understand that now but it is weird because if I run the task manually with the run task command then it works perfectly.  Only if I want it to run on the scheduled time, did it not work. Odd I believe.

Comment: Stuff running as you, has a whole environment setup around it, tasks dont..